# openGL/maths how to set direction for a point, and change that direction

Tags: opengl, math

What I need to do for my task, is to generate random points in a 3D space with some direction.  The problem is how do I define this direction? And how do I change this direction.

What I've done so far

```
-> Generate random point(x, y, z)
-> generate random latitude between 0 to 360
-> generate random longitude between 0 to 360
-> dirX = cos(lat* DEG_TO_RAD) * sin(lon * DEG_TO_RAD);
   dirY = sin(lat * DEG_TO_RAD);
   dirZ = cos(lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * cos(lon * DEG_TO_RAD);
```

Then I render by:

```
glTranslatef(pointX, pointY, pointZ);
glRotatef(dirX, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(dirY, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(dirZ, 0, 0, 1);
```

Is that fine? I wonder if I am doing something wrong either math-wise or openglwise

Comment: Strictly speaking, points do not have direction. You can interpret them as a displacement from the origin, which does have direction... Now onto the actual question - are you wanting to rotate a particular object, or the entire world? Or did you mean you want to generate points a random distance away in a certain direction?

Comment: I am sorry didn't make my self clear. this point should move, translate,  to some certain direction. That's what I mean by pointing to some particular direction and that's why I have longitude and latitude to define the angle of that direction. I use that point later as a center of some other shape, that indicates clearly the direction of that object

Comment: What you are referring to is known as a *ray*, and is usually represented as a pair of vectors, one for position and one for direction.  As far as randomly generating a direction vector, if you need better performance, but don't need a lot of accuracy, consider just choosing each component of the direction (X,Y,Z) randomly from the range [-1,1], check to make sure it's not equal to (0,0,0), and normalize it.  A single `sqrt` will be much faster than a bunch of trig functions.  The only downside is they will be biased slightly towards the edges and corners of the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by points with direction. As Andon pointed out, points don't have direction. Clarifying your question will (hopefully) turn this into a directly answerable question.

Some suggestions:

- You generate latitude and longitude randomly in degrees and then convert to radians. Just generate a random number between 0 and 2PI to begin with.
- Keep track of your own Modelview matrix. Those three `glRotatef` calls are probably not going to do what you want. This requires some linear algebra know-how but is totally worth it. You will have an intuition for 3D transformations and it will make your life far easier than having to deal with OpenGL's "convenience" methods.
- Learn up to date OpenGL. The codebase you're using has been deprecated for ~6 years and has been replaced by shader programming for even longer.